# call function from one file to another in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native. So I want to call function like below

```
First Component 
export const GridCellSelectedFirst = (n)=>{
    console.log(n)
}


export const GridCellSelectedSecond = (n)=>{
    console.log(n)

   const ToggleGridView= (n) => {
        console.log("answerNo ", n);
    }
}
```

I want to access **ToggleGridView** from  **GridCellSelectedFirst**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export const GridCellSelectedFirst = (props)=>{

  const ToggleGridView= (n) => {
        console.log("answerNo ", n);
    }

   return <ToggleGridView />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create components folder and create component folder GridCellSelectedFirst:
GridCellSelectedFirst.js:

```
const GridCellSelectedFirst = (n) => {
   ...
}

export default GridCellSelectedFirst;
```

and index.js (for endpoint):

```
export { default } from './GridCellSelectedFirst'
```

and import to other component:

```
import GridCellSelectedFirst as RandomName from './GridCellSelectedFirst';

// and use:

RandomName()
```